# How does the total number of genes increase throughout the course of evolution?

Tags: genetics, evolution

Campbell Biology says:

> A typical prokaryotic cell has  about 3,000 genes in its DNA, while a
> human cell has about  21,300 genes.

If evolution depends on random mutations occurring in the genome, this means that only certain genes are altered, but not add up to the total number. Supposing that we and the bacteria come from a common ancestor, then **what is responsible for the tremendous amount of genes that has been added throughout the evolution?**

Comment: "If evolution depends on the random mutations occurring in the genome, this means that we only alter certain genes, but not add up to the total number" - Why? Are you thinking only of point mutations? Also note that bacteria and humans have been evolving for the same length of time, and bacteria have had far, far more generations to evolve than humans have.

Comment: "Are you thinking only of point mutations?" - This is the case, mutations are the only thing I can think of right now. Can you point out other factors?

Comment: I didn't say "mutation", I said "*point mutation*". You may even only be thinking of specifically *substitution* mutations. You could start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutation to learn about others.

Comment: Look up gene duplications, copy number variations and transposons. That may give you a clue.

Comment: For a less mechanistic and more theoretical view, I would suggest looking into the [evolution of complexity](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1571651) (that's just one ref it's a large literature). Obviously expanding to a view of mutation beyond substitutions is essential, as suggested by other commenters.

Comment: It's possible that interspecies hybridization resulting in temporary allopolyploids is a driver in this. There's some interesting material on carp, I'd recommend reading.